# cucumber test problems with ajax and json even with ajax-wait-workaround

Tags: ajax, json, cucumber

In a Rails coffee-script I have this click-handler:

```
addProductToCartHandler = ()->
    $('#add_to_cart').click((event)->

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/line_items.json'
            data: {product_id:product_id}

            success: (data)->
                $('.carts_number_of_items').html(data.number_of_items)
                $('#carts_explanation').effect("pulsate",{times:2}, 200)

            error: ()->
        });

     event.preventDefault()
     return false
   )
```

This script invokes via $.ajax the following action:

```
def create
    [...]

    format.json{

         @cart.save ? 
               ( render json: {number_of_items:@cart.line_items.sum('quantity') } ) :
               ( render json: { error: t("line_items.error") } )

       }
```

That calculates the number of items in a cart, and returns json-result. **This works fine within browser, but doesn't with cucumber test:**

```
@javascript
Scenario: Add a product to a cart via ajax control
  And I follow "Cucumbers"
  When I follow "Add To Cart"
  And I wait for the ajax request to finish
  Then I should see "1 item in your cart"
```

that fails with this report:

Then I should see "1 item in your cart" #features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:24
      expected there to be content "1 item in your cart" in [...]
      **0 item in your cart\n View Your Cart [...]**
     (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)

The step "And I wait for the ajax request to finish" is:

```
When(/^I wait for the ajax request to finish$/) do
    start_time = Time.now
    page.evaluate_script( 'jQuery.isReady&&jQuery.active==0' ).
      class.should_not eql(String) 

    until page.evaluate_script('jQuery.isReady&&jQuery.active==0') or 
          (start_time + 5.seconds) < Time.now do
            sleep 1
    end
end
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you already figured this out since it was 18 months ago, thoughts for peeps having a similar problem::

- Errored out for some reason (in which case you could use 'save_and_open_page' to check the content or look at page.driver.console_messages to see if there was a JS error)
- Took more than 5 seconds (in which case you could change your 5.seconds to something much larger to see if it works)
- jQuery alias not working? (I see you're using $ - does jQuery.isReady&&jQuery.active==0 return in your console?)

Do you remember what it was?